# How do I create an anonymous Function App in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I want to call an Azure `Function App` without any **Function Keys** in the URL

Currently, I need to call it like this:

```
http://<myazureapp.com>/api/mfunc?code=3z81ag7IYWjaGdVs/Gi6BcmhROG4WJjGU3voL9UUp2iXEZZ2Vi6r7g==
```

If would like to call it like to call without the `code` query parameter:

```
http://<myazureapp.com>/api/mfunc
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Navigate to your function in the portal->  `Integrate` -> change the `Authorization level` to `Anonymous`, then you will be able to call it without `code`.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

In the new UI you have to goto Integration -> Trigger -> HTTP (req)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For anyone getting here, looking for "the code way", this setting is located in the function.json file:

```
"bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
   ...
```

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cfunctionsv2&pivots=programming-language-javascript#http-auth

Answer (score 3):

If you are writing  C# function app then you can set it in parameter attribute like below

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
ILogger log)
```